# C# GetResponse() How to timeout dynamically created url?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

This is my method, to which I am passing the url to check if it's active.
The link is being activated on the wowza service so it takes some time until it's "alive"

GetResponse is returning the 404 Error because the url is not reached.

Is there a way to get the timeout instead of 404 error if the url is not alive after specified time?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLinkIsAlive([FromQuery] string url, [FromQuery] int timeout)
{
    HttpWebResponse webResponse;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Timeout = timeout;
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        return Ok(webResponse.StatusCode);
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no timeout involved here. The **server** returned that 404 immediately. You'll have to rety a few times with a delay. BTW HttpWebRequest is obsolete. In .NET Core it's actually a compatibility wrapper over `HttpClient`. You can use `var response=await client.GetAsync(url);` to ping that URL. In ASP.NET Core you can add a [Health Check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-5.0) that pings that URL automatically

Comment: You should also consider to issue `HEAD` instead of `GET` to check existence if the wowza service supports that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use connection pooling.
It’s using IHttpClientFactory that helps to maintain the pooling and lifetime of clients

In your startup class :

```
   services.AddHttpClient<NameofyourService, NameofyourService>()
              .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(  
        p => p.WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
        {
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        }));
```

It requires **Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly**
You need to use **HttpClient** for your service. All added configurations will apply automatically.

Comment: I don't know why but it seems that after using such solution my calls hanged :/ maybe I have used this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was calling the link in the while loop every 1s and await the whole Task.

```
private async Task<bool> IsLiveStreamAlive(string streamUrl, int retriesCount = 30)
{
    try
    {
        bool res = false;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(streamUrl);
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
        while (retriesCount > 1)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            retriesCount--;
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            res = httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? true : false;
            if (res)
            {
                Log.Info(string.Format("Stream alive: {0}", streamUrl));
                break;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex);               
    }
    return false;
}
```